# neo4j 3.0.3 long merge chain taking much longer than neo4j 2.3.2

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a long and complex merge chain that creates about 140 nodes, 140 relationships, and sets 200 properties.

The query takes about 1 second to complete in neo4j 2.3.2, but takes 60 seconds in neo4j 3.0.3.

The 60 seconds seems to be CPU bound: The CPU was busy doing something for 60 seconds. I'm suspecting it's the query planner.

Looking at the query plan the 2.3.2 plan is very linear but the 3.0.3 one is slightly more concurrent.

Can someone confirm if it's the new query planner taking all this time, or if it's something else? And is there anything I can do other than downgrading back to 2.3.2?

Thanks in advance.

Additional Info:

DB hits about 2000 on 2.3.2 and 4000 on 3.0.3 but I don't think DB hits is the bottleneck here.

Heap size set to 2G on both versions.